# ¿Como manejar las rutas de imagenes en html y php?

Tags: html, imagen, rutas

Hola tengo una consulta rapida. ¿Como se manejan exactamente las rutas de imagenes en html?
Resulta que para el index
llamo a la imagen de la siguiente manera

```
  <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/mi-imagen.jpg" alt="imagen">
```

pero si creo una nueva carpeta y esta uso el mismo codigo la imagen no se muestra y en consola me muestra un error 404 al llamar la imagen. Entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de obtener la ruta absoluta de la imagen para no tener problemas a la hora de añadir subcarpetas. Cualquier consejo estaria agradecida aun estoy aprendiendo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la cual pasa eso es que el navegador entiende esa ruta como una ruta relativa. Para solucionarlo bastaría con añadir el nombre de dominio.

```
 <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://www.aquielnombredetudominio.com/img/mi-imagen.jpg" alt="imagen">
```